# Is it possible to Link a specific class or line of method from source code to the UML diagram for PlantUML IntelliJ Plugin?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, intellij-plugin, plantuml, tool-uml

I am using the PlantUML Integration plug-in to create a class diagram following the documentation:
[enter link description here](https://plantuml.com/class-diagram)

Would it be possible to link the actual class or the method line to the class diagram?

Comment: "Would it be possible to link the actual class or the method line to the class diagram?" I don't understand the question. What language are you using? Do you want to link source code with a diagram?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator yes, would it be possible to link sourcecode to the diagram or the puml file? the source code is in Java.

Comment: UML is language agnostic. So how could that ever be possible? Besides, a class diagram does not show behavior and code IS behavior. Double no sense in your question.

Comment: @qwerty_so It's possible to create a class diagram from code; several tools do this including IntelliJ. Each class (Java) is a UML class, each method (Java) shows up in its corresponding UML class. You can even make association links from instance variables, etc.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator These translators look only at the "language agnostic" parts which can map to UML. These are usually the so-called header files where class declarations are held. "Code in the sense of ocde" is what coders are paid for. Namely behavior.

Answer (score 1):

from the plugin's help text accessible from the jetbrains UI question mark icon:

> Diagram [[file links]]:
>
> - supported paths: relative to the source code file, relative to module > content roots, absolute
> - methods, fields, variables and other identifiers can be referenced by > suffix, e.g. file.java#methodName
> - paths with spaces are not supported

But I haven't got it working for me